# datediff not working in azure ml

Tags: sql, azure

I want to find difference between two dates in azure ml using apply sql transformation module. After lot of search I found that DateDiff would be helpful for doing my task. Unfortunately, it's not working. It always displays the datepart as error saying that no column in database. How to resolve it.

SQL query

```
SELECT datediff(month,Dispatch_Date,Order_Date) as Month_Diff 
from t1;
```

Error :- is not correct: SQL logic error or missing database no such column: month

Comment: Error 0069: SQL query "SELECT datediff(month,Dispatch_Date,Order_Date) as Month_Diff from t1;" is not correct:

SQL logic error or missing database

no such column: month

Comment: This is the error being displayed.

Comment: Post your command please.

Answer (score 0):

Use abbreviation for date part instead of directly using month.

```
SELECT datediff(mm,Dispatch_Date,Order_Date) as Month_Diff 
from t1;
```

Refer SQL Server documentation for more details :- [SQL Server DatePart Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms189794(v=sql.90))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried by giving abbreviation also but I got the same error "No column name mm"

Comment: I am able to run query with this syntax. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f874f/4. Can you please check if your table is missing Dispatch_Date or Order_Date column.

Comment: Both the columns are available. I am facing this problem when I am running with Apply SQL Transformation module in azure machine learning studio. Otherwise, it's working fine.

Comment: any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Datediff won't work as its not SQL but SQLLite.

You should be using the SQLLite function to get the difference

For example to get the Day difference use

```
Cast((JulianDay(EndDate) - JulianDay(StartDate)) As Integer)
```